# How to get protected value out of one class and into another

Tags: java

I have two public classes, VAG.java and XY.java. Inside VAG there's a protected value I would very much like, nay, I need to have in XY. All attempts thus far have failed. From inside XY

```
List<Double> val = VAG.valOfConcern;
```

yields `java.lang.NullPointerException`, calling

```
public List<Double> getVal( ) {
    return valOfConcern;
}
```

on my VAG object yields the same. Now I know what you're thinking; spoof, it's because the object is null, has it been initialized? It has, but maybe that particular variable hasn't been initialized yet? I'm not sure how to ask for help without just posting both full files (~1500 lines) and who's going to want to look through that anyway?

I need a wormhole, is there such a thing? Some hacky way where I can pull off some shared memory type thing in Java? I'm at my wits end, I'm about to start writing the value to a '.txt' and reading it off.

Thank you for listening to me ramble, feel free to tear me a new one, I'm frustrated.

Comment: you could post your object initialization, and check if the value of concern has a default value, if not you might need to do something to your initialized object first in order for that value to not be null.

Comment: Post the code of XY and VAG classes. Constructor and how the value is set in VAG at minimum. The title of your question is very broad and has many answers, though the question you've posted is trying to get a very specific scenario to work -- though there's not really enough to go on right now.

Comment: Can you change the class, it is considered good practice that a method that returns a List or other Collection class always returns an empty collection rather than null if there are no elements in the collection.

Comment: Add a method to VAG.java to return. It.